# Is it possible to write mysql queries in Angular.JS?

Tags: mysql, angularjs

Im new to Angular.JS and just wondering if it is possible to write mysql queries in angularjs?
I would like this as I am trying to create a messaging system in which I query the database and get the information live to the webpage.

Any help is appreciated, hope the question is reasonable. Gab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not advisable (if possible at all) as it would defeat the purpose of Angular.

You should consume data by targeting a RESTful api/service exposed by the server. The service would handle the DB access for you and provide the data to Angular using a more portable format (e.g. JSON or XML)

- Some of the basics of linking Angular and REST are described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/)
- There are related questions on SO about exposing your particular DB flavor using REST [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771485/exposing-mysql-database-table-using-rest).

This can only be a starting point but it should give you some ideas. I will try to amend this with more info as I come across it.

Comment: So the correct response would be to send say a $http to say php or JSON instead of inside Angular.JS?

Comment: yeah, let the server handle all communication with the database.

Comment: Thanks Ill make sure to do that!